# Laravel eloquent relationship for finding multilevel array

Tags: php, laravel, populate, eloquent-relationship

I am a beginner in laravel i want to create a nested api in which one model is connected with another using hasmany relationship here it is:
Model 1:

```
    class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'projects';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title','description'
         ];

         function categorywithqestions()
         {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\questionmd','cat','id');


            
         }
}
```

Model 2:

```
class questionmd extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'questions';
    public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'cat',
        'q_type',
        
        ];


    function relatedquestions()
         {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\relatedquestion','question_id','id');
         }



}
```

Model 3:

```
class relatedquestion extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'related_questions';
    public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
        'question_id',
        'title',
        'description',
        
        ];

      
}
```

and here is controller:

```
$callback = function($query) {
    $query->where('q_type', '=', 'direct_ask');
};
$questionmd = Project::whereHas('categorywithqestions', $callback)
->with(['categorywithqestions' => $callback])->get();



  
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success', 'status' => 200,'data'=>$questionmd]);
```

I want to fetch the related questions also inside the "categorywithqestions" how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

```
$questionmd = Project::whereHas('categorywithqestions', function($q) {
    $q->where('q_type', '=', 'direct_ask');
})->with(['categorywithqestions.relatedquestions'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you can use [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) helper.

The database structure should be like this.

1 Project hasMany categories
1 Category hasMany questions

```
projects
    id - integer
    name - string

categories
    id - integer
    project_id - integer
    name - string

questions
    id - integer
    category_id- integer
    commit_hash - string
```

on Project model you can do like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the deployments for the project.
     */
    public function deployments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Deployment::class, Environment::class);
    }
}
```

later on in you queries you can make

```
$questions = Project::all()->load('questions');
```